# Dict of dict issue in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm experience strange issue while resulting the dict of dict in django template.

```
data = [{'hrs': 9.0, 'ld': u'pname', 'dn': u'TS', 'ist': u'TS', 'act': u'O', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 19), 'id': 1119556},
 {'hrs': 9.0, 'ld': u'pname', 'dn': u'TS', 'ist': u'TS', 'act': u'Ti', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 21), 'id': 1119558},
 {'hrs': 2.5, 'ld': u'pname', 'dn': u'TS', 'ist': u'dmin', 'act': u'POC', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 20), 'id': 1119577},
 {'hrs': 0.5, 'ld': u'pname', 'dn': u'SMgr', 'ist': u'SMgr', 'act': u'PL', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 20), 'id': 1119578},
 {'hrs': 2.0, 'ld': u'pname', 'dn': u'SMgr', 'ist': u'TS', 'act': u'Mting', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 20), 'id': 1119579},
 {'hrs': 8.0, 'ld': u'sname', 'dn': u'holiday', 'ist': u'holiday', 'act': u'PL', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 19), 'id': 1119455},
 {'hrs': 8.0, 'ld': u'sname', 'dn': u'holiday', 'ist': u'holiday', 'act': u'PL', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 21), 'id': 1119457}, 
 {'hrs': 1.0, 'ld': u'sname', 'dn': u'TS', 'ist': u'TS', 'act': u'O', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 20), 'id': 1119566},
 {'hrs': 7.0, 'ld': u'sname', 'dn': u'PD', 'ist': u'PD', 'act': u'LOP', 'date': datetime.date(2011, 9, 20), 'id': 1119567}]
```

Using this list of dict wrote below logic

```
results = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for fetch in data:
    user = fetch['ld']
    get_id = fetch['id']
    adata = '%s/%s/%s/%s' % (fetch['dn'], fetch['ist'], fetch['act'], fetch['hrs'])
    row = results[user]
    row['user'] = user
    dt = str(fetch['date'])
    row[dt] = adata
```

this give me below output

**Results :**

```
 {u'sname': {'2011-09-21': u'holiday/holiday/PL/8.0', '2011-09-20': u'PD/PD/LOP/7.0', 'user': u'sname', '2011-09-19': u'holiday/holiday/PL/8.0'},
 u'pname': {'2011-09-21': u'TS/TS/Ti/9.0', '2011-09-20': u'SMgr/TS/Mting/2.0', 'user': u'pname', '2011-09-19': u'TS/TS/O/9.0'}}
```

**In General i need to get below output, but dict of dict print only date key value instead of of multiple key values on same date**

**Expected Output :**

```
{u'sname': {'2011-09-21': u'holiday/holiday/PL/8.0', '2011-09-20': u'TS/TS/O/1.0', '2011-09-20': u'PD/PD/LOP/7.0', 'user': u'sname', '2011-09-19': u'holiday/holiday/PL/8.0'}, 
u'pname': {'2011-09-21': u'TS/TS/Trickle/9.0', '2011-09-20': u'TS/dmin/POC/2.5', '2011-09-20': u'SMgr/Smgr/PL/0.5', '2011-09-20': u'SMgr/TS/Mting/2.0' 'user': u'pname', '2011-09-19': u'TechSupport/TechSupport/O/9.0'}}
```

one i am using below below template tag for to hash the table

**Template** :

```
@register.filter
def hash(object, attr):
  gen_context = { 'object' : object }
  try:
    value = template.Variable('object.%s' % attr).resolve(gen_context)
  except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
    value = ' '
  return value
```

**HTML :**

```
<table>
   <thead>
   <th>S.No</th>
   <th>Name</th>
  {% for dates in week_dates %}
   <th>{{dates}}</th>
   {% endfor %}
  </thead>
    <tr>
{% for fetch in data.items %}
 <tr>
 <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
 <td>{{ fetch.0 }}</td>
 {% for dates in week_dates %}
 <td>{{ fetch.1|hash:dates }}</td>
{% endfor %}                                          
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

Any help really appreciate it.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is explained in the tutorial **AT LEAST ONCE**, dictionary keys are **unique**. If you want to have multiple values for a key then you will have to fake it with a sequence.

```
{'foo': ['bar', 42]}
```

Comment: Could please help me how to do that ?

Comment: Did you even bother looking at my example?

Comment: got the point ,but jut wondering how to fake it with a sequence. sorry for  troubling you.

Comment: ... A list is always useful. Just, you know, append.

Comment: just use a try and except KeyError to achieve it... initialize the list in the except part and append to it in the try part

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple values for the same key in a dictionary. Keys must be distinct. So if you try to save a date-value pair and the date is already a key in the dictionairy, its value gets overridden. Therfore you will have to change the structure of your inner dicts, using a really unique key. What about the ids? As far as I can see, you read them in get_id but do not use them. They would be just perfect for the job. You then can save everything in a structure looking like that: `{id: (date, adata)}`, using a tuple.